# What is the difference between ngAfterContentInit() and ngAfterViewInit()?

Tags: angular

What is the difference between functions `ngAfterContentInit()` and  `ngAfterViewInit()`?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Content is what is passed as children usually to be projected at some `<ng-content>` element of a component.
View is the template of the current component.

The view is initialized after the content and `ngAfterViewInit()` is therefore called after `ngAfterContentInit()`.

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'parent-cmp',
  template: '<div #wrapper><ng-content></ng-content></div>'
})
class ParentComponent {
  @ViewChild('wrapper') wrapper:ElementRef;
  @ContentChild('myContent') content:ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log('ngAfterViewInit - wrapper', this.wrapper);
    console.log('ngAfterViewInit - content', this.content);
  }

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    console.log('ngAfterContentInit - wrapper', this.wrapper);
    console.log('ngAfterContentInit - content', this.content);
  }
}
```

```ts
<parent-cmp><div #myContent>foo</div></parent-cmp>
```

If you run this code, the output for `ngAfterViewInit - content` should be `null`.

More details about lifecycle hooks see https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

Comment: may be something was changed since Jun 22, because it returns me Object in both cases

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "returns Object". I guess it would be better to ask a new question with the code that demonstrates what you have tried

Comment: well... it's the same question - trying to understand the difference. here the code - http://plnkr.co/edit/eOOzPdpRrsaZy1caBZn3?p=preview

Comment: I can confirm that both are available in `ngAfterViewInit()` that this is really weird. Looks like a bug to me. Same behavior with components instead of plain elements http://plnkr.co/edit/lXMC9nXykT1nfwqHn1j7?p=preview

Comment: "The view is initialized before the content and ngAfterViewInit() is therefore called before ngAfterContentInit()."
Doesn't seem right:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html#!#afterview

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer if it's called after, then the content shouldn't be null in `afterViewInit`.

Comment: Maybe something changed, but this answer is no longer correct. `AfterContentInit` lifecycle occurs before `AfterViewInit`. The output for `ngAfterContentInit - wrapper` is undefined. Other outputs are defined. See this for similar plunker using v8 https://plnkr.co/edit/vZzZyrYnsB46S64B?open=lib%2Fapp.ts&deferRun=1

Answer (score 31):

The following picture shows the order of the hooks. source: [Angular Lifecycle Hooks](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html)

[image: Angular 2 life cycle hooks]

**`ngAfterContentInit` :** This is called after components external content has been initialized.

**`ngAfterViewInit` :** This is called after the component view and its child views has been initialized.

Comment: What exactly means "external content" ?

Comment: @Nexeuz external content is passed by ng-content directive

Comment: @Nexeuz external content means a way to import HTML content from outside of the component may be from parent component to a specific location of the current component.

Comment: @Laxmikant  now I have understood  "content " refers also to content projected by bindings in the component, is correct?.

Comment: ng-container is a good example for projected content @Nexeuz