# confused with ngOnInit() and ngAfterContentInit()

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm new to Angular, sorry if my questions sounds dumb. I always confused with ngOnInit() and ngAfterContentInit() lifecycle hooks. On the official docs, it says:

**ngOnInit()** : **Initialize the directive/component after Angular first displays the data-bound properties and sets the directive/component's input properties.**

**ngAfterContentInit()**: **Respond after Angular projects external content into the component's view / the view that a directive is in.**

My questions are:

Q1-For `ngOnInit()`, what does **Initialize the directive/component after Angular first displays the data-bound properties** mean? Does "Initialize " means create an instance of directive/component?

Q2-For `ngAfterContentInit()`, what's component's view means? does the view mean the associated template html in the component's templateUrl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Q1:** No, the creation of a class instance is the method `constructor` which happened  before **`ngOnInit()`**, a component is a directive with a template [data-bound properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39367423/what-is-data-bound-properties), view nodes etc.. and **`ngOnInit()`** is called after data-bound properties is ready, and as you may known, **`ngAfterViewInit()`** is called after view ready.

**Q2:** I have one example for what the "content" mean:

You define a component selector inside `app.component.html` with a text inside :

```
<custom-component>
   Some random text
</custom-component>
```

Now inside `custom-component.component.hml` you can display the text "Some random text"  using `<ng-content></ng-content>` which act as a placeholder for the text you passed down

```
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

`ngAfterContentInit()` simply mean the passing of "Some random text" into `custom-component.component.hml` view is completed.

Answer (score 0):

A1) First you need to know what data-bound properties is. This answer question should help you:

[What is data-bound properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39367423/what-is-data-bound-properties)

What creates first is the `constructor()` The constructor comes before the `ngOnInit()`

https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

A2) Yes, the view is either the xxx.component.html or the template inside of the component.ts file

https://dev.to/devpato/displaying-data-in-angular-unofficial-docs-4nd4

[What is the difference between ngAfterContentInit and ngAfterViewInit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37962821/what-is-the-difference-between-ngaftercontentinit-and-ngafterviewinit)