# How to use ViewChild correctly

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

[This Angular](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r9hwbs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fwidget-a%2Fwidget-a.component.html) [app](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r9hwbs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fwidget-a%2Fwidget-a.component.html) consists of only `app-root` component with a single `<div>` and a `<button>`.

When a button is clicked the `onClick()` function logs to console the `div_a` object with:

`console.log("...onClick() div_a:", this.div_a);`

with `div_a` defined with following statement:

`@ViewChild('div_a', { static: false }) div_a: Component;`

Question: why both the `ngOnInit` and `constructor` functions logs that the `div_a` is undefined? How to fix the problem of these functions of not being able to use `div_a` object?

Below is the link to Stackblitz project (please note that the GitHub branch that is linked to this `stackblitz` project needs to be switched from `master` to `qViewChild` branch).

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r9hwbs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fwidget-a%2Fwidget-a.component.html

[image]

Comment: Rather than `ngOnInit` or the `constructor` you need to look at the `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle hook, when ViewChild element will have been evaluated.
Also - I think that stackblitz link you posted is not right, doesn't seem to match your example code in the question (might be the wrong link?)

Comment: Thanks for your comment! The GitHub branch that is linked to the `stackblitz` project needs to be switched to `qViewChild`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the [docs](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild), `ViewChild` and `ViewChildren` queries are run before `AfterViewInit`, so you'll need to access them there.  Just accessing `div_a` won't work unless you tag it in the template.

Among others, the children you can access are:

- Any class with the @Component or @Directive decorator
- A template reference variable as a string (e.g. query `<my-component #cmp></my-component>` with @ViewChild('cmp'))

So you'll need something like this:

```
<p #myPara>
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>
```

```
import { Component, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit  {
  @ViewChild('myPara', {static: false}) paragraph;


  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.paragraph) // results in -> ElementRef {nativeElement: p}
  }
}
```

[Blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jm5vcb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Why not to use `ngAfterContentInit` instead? What is the difference between `ngAfterViewInit` and `ngAfterContentInit`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37962821/what-is-the-difference-between-ngaftercontentinit-and-ngafterviewinit

Answer (score 1):

When using `@ViewChild` DO NOT use `ngOnInit` or constructor because it is not yet loaded. Use the `ngAfterViewInit()`